# AdMob TEST_EMULATOR doesn't work alone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, admob, banner

I'm trying to implement AdMob banners on an Android app.

Even if I'm using

```
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
```

in my code to run test banners in emulator, I still get the real banners.

Also LogCat is showing the message:

```
I/Ads(2364): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("94**************************B664");
```

What's strange is the fact that the Device ID number has changed 3 times today. I wasn't able to find how and when changed. So using those ID numbers in my code, I can run test banners, until the number will change again.

```
adRequest.addTestDevices(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adRequest.addTestDevice("94**************************B664");    // My Eclipse
```

I have no Android device connected to my computer. All tests was done on Eclipse.

Please help me to understand this. Why TEST_EMULATOR doesn't work ? Why Eclipse / AVD has a Device ID ? And why Device ID is changing in this case ?

Thank you,

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/4FxQjBpB8Tk%20this%20thread) it's a bug with x86 emulators, and is fixed in the version of the AdMob library that comes with Google Play Services.